# modify styles of date picker modal

Tags: react-native, react-native-datetimepicker

I'm using [react-native-date-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-date-picker) and I want to change its buttons color (CANCEL/CONFIRM), there are no props options to do that, is there any other way I can change the color of the these buttons and the title of the modal (Select date)

Comment: Did u find any solutions for this ?

Comment: @SudipShrestha nope